# Вопрос по ОЗУ: выгрузка программы из памяти

Tags: память

Двоичные команды программы, загруженные в озу постепенно выгружаются из нее по мере их выполнения?

Или вся программа целиком в двоичном виде остается там до конца ее выполнения?

Comment: Однако вопрос. А по-конкретнее можно? Потому что вариантов ответа на такой _простой_ вопрос очень много. Давайте конкретные условия.

Comment: Нет, программа выгружается только после окончания выполнения (а скорее, блок памяти просто помечается как не занятый)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Единственный случай, когда они могут выгрузиться из ОЗУ, - это свопинг их страницы на жесткий диск. Но в виртуальной памяти они все равно остаются и при необходимости могут вернуться в ОЗУ. Но они все равно должны остаться в доступности для процессора. А вдруг где-то в последующей части программы стоит jmp на них?

Comment: или когда плату озу вытянуть с мамки =)

Comment: Тогда, боюсь, это не будет иметь уже никакого значения ((((

Comment: я к тому что случай уже не единственный, а вообще неплохо бы послать @username76 Таненбаума

Comment: Почитаю, дайте полное название книги:)

Comment: Таненбаум "современные операционные системы"

Comment: Не надо читать эту книгу, из нее вода льется вёдрами! Мне на много больше понравилась книжка Олиферов, она в два раза меньше, но зато там информация на каждой странице, а не через 10.

Comment: погуглил, нашел только "Компьютерные сети. Принципы, технологии, протоколы. Учебник для вузов" там есть про озу?

Answer (score 4):

Память для кода может выгружаться в следующих случаях:

1. При освобождении библиотеки, если она больше не используется никаким процессом.
2. При генерации кода "на лету" (JIT-компиляция) программа может освободить память, если этот код больше не нужен.

Автоматически нельзя выгружать код, потому что он выполняется не последовательно, а в нём есть ветвления, циклы и вызовы функций. Нельзя определить, может ли вызваться та или иная функция.

А почему тебя это беспокоит? Код занимает не так много места по-сравнению с данными, чтобы об этом думать.

Answer (score 3):

В дополнение к ответу [@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg), по секрету сообщу Вам, что иногда некоторые блоки команд *даже не попадают в ОЗУ*. Это называется позднее связывание или загрузка по требованию (on demand).

Если серьезно, то (м.б. кроме какой-нибудь экзотики) команды *никогда* не записываются на HDD. Если страничка с ними (при свопинге/пэйджинге) временно освобождается, то они повторно подкачиваются (при первом доступе к такой странице) не из swap, а из исходного экзешника.

Comment: Круто. А в ОЗУ команды откуда попадают, не с HDD? (Кроме какой-нибудь экзотики: флеш, cdrom...)

Comment: Конечно с HDD (флэш, cdrom...) (локального или по сети (сетевая файловая система)). Речь о том, что в swap на HDD они **не пишутся**.

Comment: Вах, надо будет со всем этим при случае подробнее разобраться

Comment: > Если серьезно, то (м.б. кроме какой-нибудь экзотики) команды никогда не записываются на HDD.

А если на HDD экзешник упакован например UPX?

Comment: @insolor, спасибо за хорошее замечание (раньше про это толком не  знал). Про работу UPX можно почитать [в man upx](http://linux.die.net/man/1/upx) , IMHO другие упаковщики работают аналгично.

Почитав этот man я понял, что исполняемый модуль, упакованный UPX распаковывает "себя" в память (если ОС позволит исполнять область данных) или во временный файл (очевидно потом делает execl()).  Про свопинг исполняемой области данных не знаю, а с файлом очевидно, все как обычно (с точки зрения ОС).

Про "экзотику", пардон, погорячился. Правильнее сказать "многие версии \*nix и м.б. других ОС".